# <force:recordData: You don't have access to this record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm using the following lightning component using `<force:recordData`
when my component loads I get the following error message

> You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help
>   or to request access.

I could not able to figure out what does it mean and what do I need to do?

I have a created a new object called "EmployeeForm__c" insert some records and here is my component looks like:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" 
                controller="EmpFormCtrl"
                access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="Id" type="String" access="public" default="" />

    <aura:attribute name="obj" type="Object" access="Private" />
    <aura:attribute name="objFields" type="Object" access="Private" />
    <aura:attribute name="objError" type="String" access="Private"  /> 

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.Id}" action="{!c.onChangeId}" />



    <aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.Id)}">
        <force:recordData aura:id="recordOps" 
                          targetRecord="{!v.obj}" 
                          targetFields="{!v.objFields}" 
                          targetError="{!v.objError}" 
                          mode="EDIT"
                          fields="Name,start_Date__c" />

        <aura:set attribute="else">
        <force:recordData aura:id="recordOps" 
                          recordId="{!v.Id}"
                          targetRecord="{!v.obj}" 
                          targetFields="{!v.objFields}" 
                          targetError="{!v.objError}" 
                          mode="EDIT"
                          fields="Name,start_Date__c" /> 
                          recordUpdated="{!c.onBlur}"/>

        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.objError))}">
      <div>
            <ui:message title="error here..." severity="error" closable="true">
          {!v.objError}
            </ui:message>
      </div>
    </aura:if>

    <lightning:card  >
        <form class="slds-form—stacked" style="margin: 10px">

            <lightning:input type="text"
                             name="Name"
                             label="Emp Name"
                             value="{!v.objFields.Name}" 
                             aura:Id="iName"
                             required="true" />
            <lightning:input name="startdate"
                             type="date"        
                             label="Start Date"   
                             value="{!v.objFields.start_Date__c}"
                             aura:Id="startdate"
                             required="true" />


            <div class="slds-text-align--center" 
                 style="margin-top:5px">

                <lightning:button variant="Brand" 
                                  label="Save" 
                                  aura:id="btnSubmit" disabled="true" onclick="{!c.onSave}" />

                <lightning:button label="Cancel" />

            </div> 
    </form>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
       helper.onInit(component,event,helper);
    },

    onChangeId: function(component,event,helper) {
      helper.onChangeId(component);  
    }, 
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    onChangeId: function(component) {
        debugger;
        var Id = component.get('v.Id');
        var recordOps = component.find("recordOps");
        if (recordOps && recordOps.getNewRecord && (Id == '' || !Id)) {
             debugger;
            recordOps.getNewRecord(
                "Employee__c ", // sObject type (objectApiName)
                null,      // recordTypeId
                false,     // skip cache?
                $A.getCallback(function() {                    
                    var rec = component.get("v.obj");
                    var error = component.get("v.objError");
                    if(error || (rec === null)) {
                        console.log("Error initializing record: " + error);
                        return;
                    }
                    debugger;
                    console.log("Record initialized: ",rec);

                })
            );
        }
    },

    onInit: function(component) {
       //initialize....        
      this.onChangeId(component);
    }, 

})
```

After debugging the code I see the error throwing in the helper class where the `onChangeId` function is on the line `recordOps.getNewRecord(....`

Comment: Try to remove redundant space character from the SObject Api name string:
`"Employee__c ", <- right here`. It should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Lightning Data Service applies sharing and FLS rules. Verify that the user has access to the specified entity, record and fields and that such a record id exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting

> "You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access."

I granted Read Acces for the object and on the fields that I was trying to display for the `lightning:outputField` inside the `lightning:recordViewForm` and it worked.